# How to manually initialise the c runtime in an exe?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, googletest, crt

I'm trying to provide my own entry point to a visual c++ executable using the linker switch "/entry". The associated Microsoft documentation goes into some detail about how to manually initialise the c runtime in a dll, but I can't grasp how to initialise it in my exe. The best I've got is that I need to call _CRT_init, but I don't know if that's a function or a macro, or where it might be defined, and Visual Studio (and msbuild) don't recognise the identifier, so no hints there.

The rationale here is that I'm attempting to unit test, with Google Test, an executable, and it won't link because main() clashes. The two approaches mentioned in the GTest FAQ aren't really generalisable and would require considerable rework to about 30 legacy executables to implement. Renaming each unit test application's main() seems like a super-easy approach, if only I could initialise the c runtime.

Comment: Googletest is not for testing executables, it is for testing
libraries. A googletest harness for testing some library requires its
own executable, with its own `main` function, to do that.

Comment: Obviously, I am attempting to test the code that is linked or compiled into arbitrary executable A by linking or compiling _the code_ from A into GTest executable B, not by running A from B, or whatever you think I'm doing. Please see [link](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-test-a-file-that-defines-main) for a description of the problem I face. I do appreciate the effort you put in to comment on a question you didn't know the answer to and tell the asker they didn't know what they were talking about.

Comment: Just a hint if you can access to the source code of the runtime library. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx) says that the initialization code should be if `libcmt.lib`. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I searched through the C Runtime source this afternoon, and the answer is "no". You cannot provide your own executable entry point not named `main` if you want to use the C Runtime. Quite aside from `_CRT_INIT()` being the an initialisation function for a dll (`mainCRTStartup()` is one of the initialisation functions for executables), `mainCRTStartup()` and its like call `main()` by name.

Answer (score 0):

- You could initialize the CRT in a standalone wrapper module which has
  main; **obj1**
- Rename the main of all existing exe modules to xx_main; **obj2, obj3.... objn**
- Link **obj1 (main)** with **(obj2, obj3.... objn)**.

> To test a foo.cc file, you need to compile and link it into **your unit
>   test program**

What's the issue with this scheme ?

[image]

Comment: This is along the lines of the first suggestion in the GTest FAQ, but more global. The only real issue here is that you must somehow exclude y.obj from being linked into the unit test exe. Totally possible, but slightly fiddly.

Comment: here y.c would be the "unit test exe" while everyting else(x.c) would be the other modules haing main(). Idea is to let the unit test exe's code intialize CRT just like any other exe and then have all other "exe" modules link to it..

Comment: But the x.c executables all need their own `main()`, or else the CRT can't be initialised during normal execution.

Comment: "But the x.c executables all need their own main()" Not now, since you'd initialize the CTR from the wrapper y.c The earlier x.c "exe program" now functions as an obj which just  has CRT dependencies. You satisfy those by linking all the objs of "exe programs" with a wrapper y.obj which has the global CRT initialization. Why wouldn't that work ?

Answer (score 0):

Though not specifically documented, it is possible to initialize the CRT in an executable in the same way it can be done in a DLL.

```
EXTERN_C BOOL WINAPI _CRT_INIT( HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved );

// ThreadProc for CreateRemoteThread, a possible use case.
DWORD WINAPI ArbitraryAlternateEntryPoint( LPVOID )
{
    _CRT_INIT( GetModuleHandle( NULL ), DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, NULL );

    // CRT functions can be used here.

    _CRT_INIT( GetModuleHandle( NULL ), DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, NULL );

    return 0;
}
```

The [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/94248/) suggests that _CRT_INIT should be called for each new thread in addition to the initial call, but in practice this is not necessary.